# For cygwin, how do I export the output in a terminal into a file?

Tags: shell, cygwin, output

I'd like to be able to export the output (and error messages) of my cygwin terminal in a file, especially since I have to click a lot of buttons in order to "mark" the stuff in the cygwin terminal (and it's desirable to minimize the amount of clicking I do).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `stderr` output of an executable can be redirected to a file with the following syntax:

```
mycommand 2> error.txt
```

If you want to redirect `stdout` (i.e. the regular program output) to the file, the command should be:

```
mycommand > output.txt
```

To redirect both the `stderr` and `stdout` output to the same file (similar to as seen on terminal), use:

```
mycommand > output_and_error.txt 2>&1
```